# Getting warning when i use withCookies()

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-cookie

I am using react-cookie in my project. When i use withCookies() i am getting warning in console log like this

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop component of type object
>   supplied to Route, expected function

How can i solve this.?

Below is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import {  withCookies } from "react-cookie";
import './Login.css';

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(values);
                const { cookies } = this.props;
                cookies.set('token', 'dfsfsd54dg2g45fg575f432sd4');
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <img className="logo-white" src={'https://cdn.medcampus.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/01131559/MC_Logo_Black.png'} alt="logo"/>
                <div className="login-container">
                    <br/>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
                        <Form.Item>
                            {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Email id!' }, {
                                    type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                                }],
                            })(
                                <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Email" size={"large"} />
                            )}
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item>
                            {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
                            })(
                                <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" size={"large"} placeholder="Password" />
                            )}
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item>
                            {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
                                valuePropName: 'checked',
                                initialValue: true,
                            })(
                                <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                            )}
                            <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">Forgot password</a>
                            <Button type="primary" size={"large"} htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">Log in</Button>
                        </Form.Item>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Login = withCookies(Form.create({ name: 'normal_login' })(NormalLoginForm));

export { Login };
```

Comment: The warning concerns an instance of a `Route` component, meanwhile, in your code, there is no such component. Could you please include it ?

Comment: `import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import {Login, Signup} from "./pages";
import {BaseLayout} from './components';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        let { cookies } = this.props;
        console.log(cookies.getAll());

        return <div>
            <Route path="/" exact component={BaseLayout} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </div>;
    }
}

export default withCookies(App);`

Comment: This is my App.js file code. In this file i have added routing code @MohamedELAYADI

Comment: Can you please show your `pages.js` file ?

Comment: pages is the directory. In that directory we have all page components with one index.js file. That index.js file consist the below code. `export * from './login/Login';
export * from './signup/Signup';`

Comment: That's it, i will write a possible answer for your issue, please note that this has nothing to do with `withCookies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, you are exporting all imports from your containers' files as default, so basically you'll get an object, not a function(the exact export).

To prevent this, there is several ways to do it:

- Import your container in `App` from its own file.
- in `index.js` of `pages`, you can do this :

```
import { Login } from `LoginContainerFile`;
import { Comp1} from `Comp1ContainerFile`;
import { Comp2} from `Comp2ContainerFile`;
export { Login, Comp1, Comp2 };
```

Good luck and hope it resolves your problem.